# Share azure app service for 1 website and 1 web api

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to figure out if it's possible to share 1 "Azure App Service" for two different projects (which thus run simultaneously):

- 1 .NET 4.5 Website (MVC5)
- 1 .NET core WebApi

Or is one Azure App Service limited to exactly one website/webapi?

PS: I know I can mix WebApi Controllers and MVC controllers, but I do not have the possibility to merge the two projects into one either .NET 4.5 or one .NET core project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can host more than one app on one App Service Plan. Your apps can even run different stacks, e.g. three Node sites, two ASP.NET MVC5 sites and one PHP API.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview:

> Web Apps, Mobile Apps, API Apps, Function Apps (or Functions), in Azure App Service all run in an App Service plan. Apps in the same subscription, region, and resource group can share an App Service plan.
>
> All applications assigned to an App Service plan share the resources defined by it. This sharing saves money when hosting multiple apps in a single App Service plan.

Comment: You are talking about an 'App Service Plan'. Does that mean that I should create two 'App Service 's which are both associated to the same 'App Service Plan'? And does that mean one additional 'App Service ' does not cost extra money?

Comment: If the plan is at least on Basic tier. Then it has dedicated instances that your apps use. You pay for instances there, so amount of apps doesn't matter.

Comment: And can I use same base URLs for the different apps? Can I use myazurewebsite.com for the website, and myazurewebsite.com/api/MyApi/Action/Id for the WebApi?

Comment: You can use subdomains to point to different apps. If you want to use the URL scheme you describe, then you'll need an Application Gateway in front of it to take care of the routing: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-gateway/

Comment: OK the subdomain stuff is not really something I need to learn now, so I'll leave that for later. Can you help me with one last part? How do I actually get the above done? I have a new "free" Azure account, and 1 app service, and 1 service plan. I have 1 solution (VS2017) with 2 projects as stated in my question. How do I get my web api and my website in my azure app service? Just publishing will "erase" the previous one, correct?

Comment: No, there's a wizard you go through when you click Publish. Just pick a new name for the 2nd app.

Comment: @evilSnobu thanks a lot for your help. It indeed was just as simple as that! (created a new solutions, added new website + webapi, published them both and can use both at the same time). Not sure what I messed up the first time, but anyway: thaaaanks!!